# AVPLayer to play video from URL in Firebase Database

Tags: ios, database, firebase, avplayer

I have prototype cells that automatically pull text from a Firebase database. I want to incorporate videos into this as well. How would I use AVPlayer to play a video from a URL in the FireBase database. I want it to be as automatic as possible.

I am not an experienced developer and am stumbling through this, so please provide "baby level" answers.

Here is the code for the cells that pull from firebase.

```
        //
//  FirebaseVidoes.swift
//  Faces of the Holocaust Photographic History
//
//  Created by New User on 8/25/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 New User. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

struct postStruct {
let title : String!
let message : String!
//let image : UIImage!
}


class FirebaseVidoes: UITableViewController {


var posts = [postStruct]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: 
"polandBackgroundBlur.jpg"))


    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()


databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, 
with: {

        snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let title = snapshotValue?["title"] as? String
        let message = snapshotValue?["message"] as? String
        //let image = snapshotValue?["image"] as? UIImage

        self.posts.insert(postStruct(title: title, message: message) 
, at: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    })


    //post()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func post(){

    let title = "Title"
    let message = "Message"


    let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["title": title as AnyObject,
                                        "message": message as 
AnyObject]


    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return posts.count

}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

    let label1 =  cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title

    let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].message

    //let image1 = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImage
        //image1.UIimage = posts[indexPath.row].image



    return cell!

}




}
```

And here is the AVPlayer code:

```
//  VideoTestViewController.swift
//  Faces of the Holocaust Photographic History
//
//  Created by New User on 8/26/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 New User. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class VideoTest: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func watchVideoDidClick(_ sender: Any) {

    playExternalVideo()
}

let videoURL = "SOMEVIDEOURL"

func playExternalVideo(){

    let videoURL = NSURL(string: self.videoURL)!

    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

    playerViewController.player = player

    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        () -> Void in
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

How can I merge these to get videos that automatically populate to the cell.

**EDIT** Here is revised code

```
   //Code Beginning    
   import UIKit
   import Firebase
   import AVKit
   import AVFoundation

   struct postStruct {
let title : String!
let message : String!
let url : URL!
//let image : UIImage!
```

}

class FirebaseVidoes: UITableViewController {

```
var posts = [postStruct]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "polandBackgroundBlur.jpg"))


    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {

        snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let title = snapshotValue?["title"] as? String
        let message = snapshotValue?["message"] as? String
        let url = snapshotValue?["url"] as? URL
        //let image = snapshotValue?["image"] as? UIImage

        self.posts.insert(postStruct(title: title, message: message, url: url) , at: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()




    })


    //post()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

/* func post(){

```
    let title = "Title"
    let message = "Message"


    let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["title": title as AnyObject,
                                        "message": message as AnyObject]


    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)


} */

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return posts.count

}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

    let label1 =  cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title

    let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].message



    //let image1 = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImage
        //image1.UIimage = posts[indexPath.row].image



    return cell!




}

func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var selectedIndex = indexPath

    let url = URL(string: "url")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean that you need to play the video inside of the cell? Or you want them to play on the separate screen with AVPlayer controls like stop, pause, volume etc?

Comment: Either would be fine with me. I just have no idea how to even begin. Seems like it would be easier to have a play button that opened into a new view, but I dont know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for showing in on a new screen:

1. import:  import AVKit, import AVFoundation
2. Then when user taps on the cell (in didSelectRow method of TableView)

   ```
   let videoURL = URL(string: "url")
   let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
   let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
   playerViewController.player = player
   self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
       playerViewController.player!.play()
   }
   ```

Making it play inside the cell is harder. As you commented, this will work for you for now.

**EDIT**: answering your question in comment:
That should be easy. As I see you already have this:

```
self.posts.insert(postStruct(title: title, message: message), at: 0)
```

That means you are adding new `Post` object into the `posts` array. Then you reload data.

So now, I guess your `snapshotValue` supposed to have an URL, right? Since if you are saying that you need to play the video then where does the URL comes from? So my guess is that snapshot has this url. So you need to add to your Post object the new property which is an url.

So now every cell will contain a Post object which has an url. And when user taps on it, you just play that url of the post. Is it clear?

EDIT2:
just do this:

`let url = posts[indexPath.row].url`

EDIT3:

1. change your line 44 to this:

`let urlString = snapshotValue?["url"] as? String`

`let url = URL(string: urlString!)`

2. change your didSelect method to this:
   `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: Right. I can make the video play. What I am having a hard time with is adding that functionality to the Firebase aspect.

Comment: How do I make it automatically populate the video in the prototype cell?

Comment: answered your question in my answer: see **EDIT** part.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @WP please accept the answer if it helped you and if you think it's correct and solves your issue. Let's keep the stackoverflow's culture :)

Comment: I will try it today.

Comment: `let url = URL(string: "url")` is the issue. Please be more attentive. It's core of being a programmer.

Comment: Please advise as to what I should do. Like I mentioned before, I am not a developer, but am trying to learn by teaching myself. Thks

Comment: It recognizes that the cell is tapped, but it still doesn't play the video.The project is in Github

Comment: send me a link please?

Comment: It's private. Can add you as collaborator. What is your Git user? Will still be sure to mark you as answerer here.

Comment: what's your skype? or something where i can chat you

Comment: or. check out the update. i fixed it and played the video :)

Comment: just edited. check it out. make sure follow both 2 steps